# In IBM Api connect Unable to Change the response Content-Type to “application/json; charset=UTF-8”

Tags: apiconnect

I am using `apic.setvariable('message.headers.Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');` property in gateway script to change response header. Which is not working.

Suspecting, the `content-type` is not `charset=utf8`, which in turn overwriting the `content-type` header. How to use Map Policy to transform the response body to `charset=utf-8`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324848/unable-to-change-content-type-to-application-json-charset-utf-8